# Pick a particular field out of an inner array

Tags: php, arrays

before the traitement :

print_r ($value) =

```
Prise en chargeListe des d�p�tsSaisie parflashageSupervisionSupervision des fluxSuivi des flux informatiquesAdministrationContr�le des RADMContr�le des RPECSurveillanceJournalJournal de bordAudit des depots
```

the traitement

```
foreach ($toto as $data)
{
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $value = $value. ',';
        $tab = explode(",", $value);
        print_r($tab);
    }
}
```

After the traitement :

print_r($tab) =

```
Array ( [0] => Prise en charge [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Liste des d�p�ts [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Saisie par flashage [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Supervision [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Supervision des flux [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Suivi des flux informatiques [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Administration [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Contr�le des RADM [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Contr�le des RPEC [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Surveillance [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Journal [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Journal de bord [1] => ) Array ( [0] => Audit des depots [1] => )
```

My question : Why he not give me the array like that :

```
Array
// (
//    [0] => Prise en charge
//    [1] =>  Liste des d�p�ts
//    [2] =>  etc
//    [3] =>  etc
//    [4] =>  etc
//    [5] =>  etc
// )
```

Here is a sample of the original `$toto` data:

```
var_dump($toto) = array(13) { [0]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(15) "Prise en charge" } [1]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(16) "Liste des dépôts" } [2]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(19) "Saisie par flashage" } [3]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(11) "Supervision" } [4]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(20) "Supervision des flux" } [5]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(28) "Suivi des flux informatiques" } [6]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Administration" } [7]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(17) "Contrôle des RADM" }
```

php version: less than 5.5

Comment: because you exploded each individual section, not the whole thing. Wait until you've added commas to everything, and _then_ explode the whole line

Comment: I did not understand, i have to add the ',' in the $data ?

Comment: You added it to the $value. not the $data. and then you exploded the $value. So fine, add it to $value. But then don't do the explode until after the loop. Unless I misunderstood. What is the content of $toto? It's not 100% clear where you are starting from, exactly.

Comment: var_dump($toto) = array(13) { [0]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(15) "Prise en charge" } [1]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(16) "Liste des dépôts" } [2]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(19) "Saisie par flashage" } [3]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(11) "Supervision" } [4]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(20) "Supervision des flux" } [5]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(28) "Suivi des flux informatiques" } [6]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Administration" } [7]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(17) "Contrôle des RADM" }

Comment: I retrieve my SQL query in my $toto and i want to isolate the text, that's why i used 2 foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you simply want to pick a particular field out of each inner array.

You can solve this in one line as follows, without messing about with loops, commas etc:

```
print_r(array_column($toto, 'name'));
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Prise en charge
    [1] => Liste des dépôts
    [2] => Saisie par flashage
    [3] => Supervision
    [4] => Supervision des flux
    [5] => Suivi des flux informatiques
    [6] => Administration
    [7] => Contrôle des RADM
```

etc.

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/09d7cde83b58b8c6a84be66f4fcc45d3f4fef6a8

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

---

Additional:

If you don't have the array_column function available, then it's still fairly simple to solve like this:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($toto as $data)
{
    $output[] = $data["name"];
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: the function array_column() is for php 5.5 ? because i've got a fatale error when i use it

Comment: yes, that's when it was introduced. Are you running an older version? If so you should consider upgrading urgently, as you are not receiving critical security patches and other updates. See http://php.net/supported-versions.php . P.S. In your question you didn't specify your PHP version, so I assumed (reasonably, I would say) that you had a recent version.

Comment: I understand now, sorry I should have said it before. I can not upgrade for php 7 or 5.5, I do not have the right in my company: / I will change the title so sorry

Comment: Hm, you should warn your company they are endangering their security, and that of their data (or their clients' data, if that's what the application holds). Running an unsupported version is irresponsible, frankly. Upgrading is not that hard, in most cases, and certainly the impact can be tested. Even if it's not your responsibility, you should make them aware that you think it's a bad practice.

Comment: Anyway, I added a simple alternative solution as an extra part of the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working ! i will say it to my tutor about php version but you know im an only trainee :/